# getting connection string error with prisma

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, prisma

```
`schema.prisma file`

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id       String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name     String?
  email    String  @unique
  password String
  posts    Post[]
}

model Post {
  id       String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  slug     String
  title    String
  body     String
  author   User   @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId String @db.ObjectId
}


`prisma/index.js`
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client/edge');
require('dotenv').config();

const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  datasources: {
    db: {
      url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    },
  },
});

module.exports = prisma;


`.env connection string :` 
DATABASE_URL= mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.rhnyczz.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

i got an error while singup using postman :Error: PrismaClientKnownRequestError:
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation:

Error validating datasource `db`: the URL must start with the protocol `prisma://`
at exports.signup (D:\prisma_backend\controllers\userControllers.js:20:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

`please anyone tell me how to rectify this error`

Comment: What command are you running to generate `PrismaClient`?

Comment: `npx prisma generate`